# Properly parallelising FindRoot for multiple starting values

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, parallelization

I have a problem I want to find numerical solutions for with different starting variables. Let `F` be a vector supposed to vanish, which in its definition includes the free symbols `a`, `b`, `c`. Then I run

```
output={alpha,beta,gamma, F};
initialconditions={{gamma, 1}};
Export["numerical.csv",
    N[
        ParallelTable[
            output /. FindRoot[F==0, initialconditions],
            {alpha, 0 Degree, 100 Degree, 20 Degree},
            {beta, 0 Degree, -100 Degree, -20 Degree}
        ]],
    "TSV"
]
```

Which causes `Launching kernels...` to appear on the screen. When I check in `htop` what the Kernels do, I notice that all are sleeping except for the main one; so nothing seems to be run in parallel. The same happens with the following alternative I tried:

```
tasks = Table[
    ParallelSubmit[
        {F, initialconditions, output, alpha, beta},
        output /. FindRoot[F==0, initialconditions]
    ],
    {alpha, 0 Degree, 100 Degree, 20 Degree},
    {beta, 0 Degree, -100 Degree, -20 Degree}
];
result = WaitAll[tasks];
Export["numeric.csv", result, "TSV"]
```

What am I doing wrong about parallelisation?

**Edit:** The problem does not seem to be about `FindRoot`; at least, when I run it ouside of any parallel context:

```
Do[
    Print[DecimalForm[N[output]] /. FindRoot[F==0, initialconditions]],
    {alpha, 0 Degree, 100 Degree, 20 Degree},
    {beta, 0 Degree, -100 Degree, -20 Degree},
]
```

it finds solutions; though very slowly, which is why I want to run this problem in parallel.

Comment: I don't know about the parallelization aspect, but does the `FindRoot` work outside the `ParallelTable`?  Could you include a sample problem?

Comment: @ChrisK See my edit. I will be looking for a complete example that shows the problem.

Comment: Thanks!  From your question, it seems more about finding roots across a range of parameter values, rather than a range of starting values (`initialconditions` is always `{gamma,1}`).  Is that right?